# When creating an intent for a specific component, when would "this" not be the first argument of the constructor?

Tags: android, android-intent

Would there ever be an instance when the context would not be "this"?
I just can't seem to think of a way that the context launching the other activity could be anything but itself.

Constructor for creating an intent for a specific component:
Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have your answer: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/ , Really good post!.
Scroll to Context Capabilities section and you see that to start an activity or show a dialog you need the activity context.